# Need to put an array of data starting row 1 with mysql using mysql

Tags: mysql

So I filled in a table with data. Now i have to create a new column and insert data starting again from row 1. MySQL however will put all of it at the end of the table (since it's with autonumber). Also, I can only use mysql scripts, I think. I am using phpmyadmin, however have no experience with php at all. is it possible to do?

This is what I've tried

```
    SET @ArrayDataID = 1;
    SET @rowdata = "'Jewelry', 'Apparel', 'Bags', 'Shoes', 'Accesories'";
    WHILE @ArrayDataID <= 7
    DO
    INSERT INTO ARRAYDATA (MainCategory)
    VALUES (rowdata(rownum))
    WHERE ID = rownum;
    SET rownum = rownum + 1;
    END WHILE;
```

I also tried a procedure but also no luck

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE AddCategories()
    BEGIN
    DECLARE ArrayDataID INT DEFAULT 1;
    DECLARE rowdata VARCHAR DEFAULT ('Jewelry', 'Apparel', 'Bags', 'Shoes', 'Accesories');
    WHILE (rownum <= 6) DO
    INSERT INTO ARRAYDATA (MainCategory)
    VALUES (rowdata(rownum))
    WHERE ID = rownum;
    SET rownum = rownum + 1;
    END WHILE;
    END
```

Help, anyone? thanks in advance.

Comment: _Now i have to create a new column and insert data starting again from row 1_  .... why?  I can't think of a worse way to abuse a database.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: well, i want to make a data driven website and had thought to make one table to contain all of my arrays to simplify everything. I am new to all of this, so I am learning everything from level 0. so far i have my form ready to populate, i just need the arrays. I have in the database and now cant put the second one there